# Autocomplete backslashes in zsh

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, zshrc

Is there a zsh script that would allow me to auto complete spaces with backslashes?
For example:

assume there is a folder called "My folder" with a space in between.
If I want to get inside, I

```
cd My\ folder
```

However, I want a way to type

```
cd My folder
```

and zsh will automatically know to put a backslash so I don't have to.

Comment: Suppose you had three folders: `My`, `folder`, and `My folder`. How would `zsh` know whether the space was a word separator or a character to treat literally?

Comment: You can only cd in to one directory, so zsh would have to assume that I want the space as a word seperator and thus i want to go in to 'My folder'

Comment: `zsh` supports a two-argument version of `cd`, in which the 2nd argument replaces the first argument in the name of the current directory. I gave a bad example, but there is still ambiguity as to how `zsh` should interpret the space.

Answer (score 1):

A little late on the answer, but this should allow you to do what it is you're looking to do as well as retain the normal behavior for the `cd` command and also take you to your `~` directory if no directory is given.

Add to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```
function cd() {
    new_directory="$*";
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        new_directory=${HOME};
    fi;
    builtin cd "${new_directory}"
}
```

However your ZSH should have autocompletion built in, in which case you can enter the first few letters of the directory that you're trying to cd into, then hit <kbd>tab</kbd> and it should complete the directory name or give a list of directories if more than one matches.

Answer (score 0):

You could Make an alias with "Myfolder" and run that in a zsh script.

```
alias -g "Myfolder"="My\ folder"    ---> cd Myfolder
```

I don't know if there is a way to make it possible with having the space in between the words. If it has to be my "My folder" then I don't know that I can help you.